# Linux install error " dracut Warning: Can't mount root filesystem. "

Tags: linux, installation, fedora

I am installing Fedora 16.

I just insert CD to install Fedora 16 in my laptop
however, I am getting this error like "dracut Warning: Can't mount root filesystem."

http://cfile7.uf.tistory.com/image/176BAA3C4EBF9F89051FA7   <--- like this

I am not really sure how to fix it. (this is the first time to install Fedora 16 in my laptop)

In my laptop , I previously installed Windows 7 Professional. I have not install any kind of Linux before.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

In the kernel path from grub type after your code:

```
acpi=off irqpoll
```

Answer (score 0):

That error probably indicates that something is wrong with the CD you are using.

[Follow the instructions here](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/16/html/Burning_ISO_images_to_disc/sect-Burning_ISO_images_to_disc-Validating_the_Files.html) to verify the ISO you downloaded is valid.  If not, redownload the ISO.  If so, try burning a new CD.